# Best solutions for merging two controllers/views in CakePhp

Tags: cakephp

I have two models:

```
Book
Category
```

I have two views:

```
books/browse
```

In this view there is paginated list of books, with sort options, book language select, author/title filters and so on. One thing there isn't - book category tree. In fact this controller takes as a parameter category_id and displays only books from this category.

```
categories/tree
```

This view (controller) finds the category tree and it takes one parameter -> category_id -> to determine how to print the tree (to show all parent nodes, and parents list and so on).

Now I need a view (for example browsetree) where there is category tree on the left and a list of books (with all stuff) on the right.

What will be best solution to accomplish this? (The problem is also I want to be able to save the link to book browse view with all it's params (category_id param + sorting + few GET params for filtering) and I also don't want to rewrite any view or controller method...

-------------- edit

Okay I have my tree in element 
    categorytree
and it looks like this:

```
$params = $this->requestAction('/categories/tree/'.$category_id); 
print_category($params['tree'][0],$params['parents'],$category_id);
```

The $category_id is passed to the element as parameter.
This is inside /books/browse:

```
<?php echo $this->element('categorytree', array("category_id" => $category_id)); ?>
```

What I need is that in categorytree element I want that each tree node was a valid link to /books/browse based on current url that books/browse is loaded from.
I mean that the url might be:

```
books/browse/34/sort:asc/page:4?author=Author&something=something
```

I could get this link 
    inside /books/browse/... 
view and pass it to the element and then parse it to replace /34/ (it's category id) with other categories... But is there any easier / more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Put your category tree in an element and use [CakePHP's requestAction](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#passing-variables-into-an-element) to get it's data from the Category controller.

You can keep your tree view in the Books area (which makes sense, since that's what the user is browsing) - up to you which view you put it in.

Bottom line, the user is searching books, so that's where the view and the code should be.  Use the Category tree to just pass a variable for which category you want to use in your query against the books.

Comment: thanks :) - 1 more question - when I will do as you say, will it be possible to refresh book list with ajax without reloading the tree? I mean can somehow Element (links in category tree) refresh part of view in which Element is embedded?

Comment: Sure - javascript can update any element you tell it to update with any information you pass it.  And the links can use ajax to retrieve the info from whichever controller/action you'd like.

Comment: I edited my post because I am not sure how to do it (for now without any ajax, I want to just create valid links)

Comment: If the category tree does not change often don't forget to cache otherwise you may suffer a performance hit

Comment: user606521 - if you have additional technical questions, please ask them as new questions instead of appending your initial question.